# Erro com cálculo simples no javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldade para fazer uma conta usando javascript:

### javascript

```
num1 = $("#num1").val(); // exemplo 2
num2 = $("#num2").val(); // exemplo 50

result = num1+num2;
```

Esse código resulta em 250 ao invés de 52

Parece que ele está concatenando ao invés de somar.

Como arrumar esse erro?

Comment: Ele retorna 250 porque está a assumir que tens duas strings.

Comment: Sempre que usar parseInt use (valor, **radix**), pois, no javascript números que começam com 0 é do tipo octal, então se o valor de "#num1" e "#num2" for por exemplo 03 e 05 ele vai fazer a soma em octal, para evitar vc deve usar `parseInt($("#num1").val(), 10)` :)

Comment: Isso não é um erro o método val() do jQuery retorna uma String o operador "+" do javascript serve tanto para somar quanto para concatenar, sugiro que você dê uma olhada em http://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você precisa transformar em inteiro para isso use a função `parseInt` primeiro por exemplo:

```
num1 = parseInt($("#num1").val()); // exemplo 2
num2 = parseInt($("#num2").val()); // exemplo 50

result = num1+num2;
```

Comment: Para ficar perfeito o ideal seria usar `parseInt($("#num2").val(), 10)` pois se o valor for por exemplo "07" + "05" ele interpreta como octal.

Comment: @LeandroAmorim +1, embora nesse caso não faça diferença... Exemplos melhores seriam "010" (8) e "020" (16)

Comment: Eu recomendaria Number pelo fato de que o valor resgatado pode retornar algo no formato float.

Answer (score 7):

Você está por padrão do javascript concatenado, pois no val() ele pega uma string, para realizar a soma você precisa converter para numeros, que podem ser float(numeros com ,) ou int(apenas inteiros),

```
num1 = parseInt($("#num1").val()); // exemplo 2
num2 = parseFloat($("#num2").val()); // exemplo 50,4

result = num1+num2;
```

Answer (score 6):

Os valores são textuais e não numéricos. Para receber valores exatos, independentes de serem flutuantes ou inteiros, pode utilizar Number():

```
result = Number(num1) + Number(num2)
```

Ou pode usar esta solução também:

```
result = num1 * 1 + num2 * 1
```

Em todo caso, se o texto contiver caracteres que não sejam numéricos, precisará utilizar parseInt(string) ou parseFloat(string).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa de converter para numero usando por exemplo o  [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

No javascript o sinal `+` em tipo `string` é para concatenar, em tipo `number` é para somar.

O valor que você está a receber do `.val()` é uma `string`. Sendo uma string o código pensa que você quer juntar `50` depois do `2` e isso é `250`.

**Dê uma olhada aqui:**

```
num1 = $("#num1").val(); 
num2 = parseInt($("#num2").val()); // usando o parseInt()
console.log(typeof num1); // string
console.log(typeof num2); // number
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/zMP78/)